# @Cacheble annotation on no parameter method

Tags: spring, ehcache, spelevaluationexception

I want to have `@Cacheable` annotation on method with no parameter. In that case, I use @Cacheable as follows

```
@Cacheable(value="usercache", key = "mykey")
public string sayHello(){
    return "test"
}
```

However, when I call this method, it doesn't get executed and it get exception as below

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'mykey' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject' - maybe not public?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It seems that Spring doesn't allow you to provide a static text for the cache key in the `SPEL`, and it doesn't include as default the name of the method on the key, so, you could be in a situation when two methods using the same `cacheName` and without a key would potentially cache different results with the same key.

The easiest workaround is to provide the name of the method as the key:

```
@Cacheable(value="usercache", key = "#root.methodName")
public string sayHello(){
return "test"
}
```

This would set `sayHello` as the key.

If you really need a static key, you should define a static variable in the class, and use `#root.target`:

```
public static final String MY_KEY = "mykey";

@Cacheable(value="usercache", key = "#root.target.MY_KEY")
public string sayHello(){
return "test"
}
```

You can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context) the list of SPEL expressions that you can use in your key.

Comment: Can you please explain this line - A static key (mykey in your case) would also not make sense, as Spring already binds the Cache to the specific method.      so what would be the key that will be stored in cache if i dont mention it explicitely

Comment: @user3534483 sorry, i was wrong about the default key that Spring uses. I have edited the answer and added the right information.

Comment: "It seems that Spring doesn't allow you to provide a static text for the cache key in the SPEL". This is wrong as you can use String literals. E.g. I use in production `private static final String CACHE_KEY_ALL = "'##all'";` and works like a charm. Anyway the answer rocks so I will not downvote

Comment: @Ruben Why do we need key for no argument method? I can use #1  @Cachable("cache1") method1() #2 @Cachable("cache2") method2() . Is this incorrect way ?

Comment: This is a partially correct, and partially incorrect answer. Please see the answer below by Clif. That should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 47):

Try adding single quotes around `mykey`.  It's a SPEL expression, and the singles quotes make it a `String` again.

```
@Cacheable(value="usercache", key = "'mykey'")
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it is fully correct and directly answers the question.

Comment: This is something usually every java developer misses, i.e. adding single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the key parameter. Spring will then put the value with key [SimpleKey.EMPTY](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/SimpleKey.html#EMPTY) into the cache:

```
@Cacheable("usercache")
```

Alternatively (apart from using SPEL outlined in the other solutions) you can always inject the `CacheManager` and manually handle it.

Comment: how to solve this problem on unit testing?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519570/spring-boot-2-testing-cacheable-with-mockito-for-method-without-arguments-is

Comment: @Gowrav maybe Mockito is interfering?

Comment: seems like it, I was unable to get around, if the api has a parameter its working as expected, but without arguments having the same issue, maybe we should log a bug against mockito

Comment: @Gowrav try doReturn(...).when(...). Sometimes reordering this way helps make Mockito behave.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem is the syntax of key is not right

```
@Cacheable(value = "name", key = "#object.field1+object.field2")
```

Right is need # before key items:

```
@Cacheable(value = "name", key = "#object.field1+#object.field2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed to add # before id, like key must be look like, key="#id" not key="id"

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@Cacheable(key = "#id", value = "book")
public Book getBookById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return bookService.getBookById(id);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add # in the key

```
@Cacheable(value="usercache", key = "#mykey")
public string sayHello(){
    return "test"
}
```

Comment: This is for variable replacement if #mykey is a defined variable somewhere. However, it is not, and therefore, will result in a null key error.