# After @CachePut findAll() doesn't give result from cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache

I am learning spring boot caching to apply this concept in our organization's project and I made a sample project called employe cache. I have four methods in my controller and service component insert, update, get, and getAll.For insert and get `@Cacheable` is working perfectly. Now I am calling `getAllEmployee()` first time then it is fetching data from the database. After that I am trying to update with `@CachePut` it updates the value in the database and again I am calling `getAllEmployee()` then it didn't return updated value from the cache. I also refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RC1/reference/html/cache.html) for `@CachePut`. I also refer to some other documents like [this](https://medium.com/@buddhiprabhath/spring-boot-crud-example-with-caching-c2c9b7fd8f05) and [this](https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks) but I didn't solve my problem. Also, When I am calling, no error is raised.
What I Tried is
These are my two APIs from `EmplyeeController.java`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/updateSalary")
private Boolean updateSalary(@RequestParam int salary, @RequestParam Integer id) {
    return empService.updateSalary(salary, id);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/getAllEmployee")
private Object getAllEmployee() {
    List<EmployeeMapping> empList = empService.getAllEmployee();
    return !empList.isEmpty() ? empList : "Something went wrong";
}
```

These are my two methods from `EmployeeService.java`. I applied different keys to update the method but didn't work. My `getAll()` method has no parameter so I tried all the keys techniques for no parameter methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383366/cacheble-annotation-on-no-parameter-method) then also I didn't get any results.

```
@CachePut(key = "#root.method.name")
public Boolean updateSalary(int salary, int id) {
    System.err.println("updateSalary method is calling in service");
    if (empRepo.salary(salary, id) != 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Cacheable(key = "#root.method.name")
public List<EmployeeMapping> getAllEmployee() {
    return empRepo.findAllEmployee();
}
```

These are my two methods from `EmployeeRepository.java`. I used `@SqlResultSetMappings` and `@NamedNativeQueries`in `EmployeeMetaModel.java` with `EmployeeMapping.java` but there is no error in native query in `EmployeeMetaModel.java` because it's giving result from database.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("update employee_cache e set e.salary = ?1 where e.id = ?2")
int salary(int salary, int id);

@Query(name = "EmployeeListQuery", nativeQuery = true)
List<EmployeeMapping> findAllEmployee();
```

Kindly help me to get rid of this I just need an updated value from the cache using `getAllEmployee()` after `updateSalary()` called.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with how you've defined caching via annotations. Your `@CachePut` and `@Cacheable` don't use the same cache key. What you should actually have is something like this:

```
@CachePut(value = "employees", key = "T(org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey).EMPTY")
public List<EmployeeMapping> updateSalary(int salary, int id) {
    // update salary and return the list of employees
}

@Cacheable(value = "employees")
public List<EmployeeMapping> getAllEmployee() {
    // return the list of employees
}
```

Here `@CachePut`and `@Cacheable` have the same cache key.d Now, when you call the `updateSalary()` method, `@CachePut` will replace the existing cached value for key *"employees"*, with the result of the method i.e. list of employees with updated salary.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer @Igor. I tried your solution but as per the rules we have to follow SPEL for key declaration so we have to add `#employees` not only `employees`. Otherwise, It will give `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException`

Comment: Also, I tried with `#employees` but it's not working and I try `@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "employee")` and `@CachePut(value = "employee", key = "#employees")` it's also not working.

Comment: @DeepDalsania I've updated my answer. The SpEL expression for key in `@CachePut` should match the key value Spring uses to cache the result of  `@Cacheable` annotated method (i.e. getAllEmployee)

Comment: I tried your updated answer @Igor. First I called `getAllEmployee()`. It gave the result by firing a query. Secon I called `updateSalary()`. It updates data firing a query. Third I again called `getAllEmployee()` and it gave exception that `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.List
 at com.spring.cache.service.EmployeeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90d3116e.getAllEmployee(<generated>)` at where I called my service  `getAllEmployee()` to controller.

Comment: It appears that you have not updated `updateSalary`, and it still returns **Boolean**. The `updateSalary` should return same type of result as ` getAllEmployee` i.e. the **List<EmployeeMapping>** for `@CachePut` to work properly. This result is the value that `@CachePut` uses to replace existing value in cache. I case you do need boolean result from `updateSalary` method, then you'll have to update the cache within `updateSalary` using `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` instead of `@CachePut` annotation.